# Creating a GUI (PHP/MYSQL)

Tags: php, database

I need some consultation here. I am a C# developer, and for just about all of my applications, I enjoy building the GUI up before writing most of the code (it's just how my brain functions).I am very new to PHP/MYSQL, and I am having a LOT of trouble wrapping my head around the right way of doing what it is I am trying to do (see below). Please keep in mind I am *only* looking for graphical help here - what would you do to make this look sleek?

I have a database which will hold a decent amount of customers. For example purposes, let's say this database will hold 50 customers. The table which holds all customer information is 5 columns across, and, in this case, 50 rows down. I need to have the ability to add new customers *along with* the ability to delete old customers from the database. (* AGAIN * I am not looking for code here, but advice on how to go about designing this page). For adding new customers, I have a seperate .php page with an html form, and five textboxes. This will create a new row. Deleting / editing customer information is what I have yet to come up with. I can't decide if these functions should be placed onto a separate page or the same one as the database.

Basically, any ideas / help at all will be much appreciated.

Comment: look at jqgrid http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx

Comment: Looking at that, I think that's a pretty good solution.

Comment: Very great program, although I am really interested in trying to do this stuff myself. Once I get a little more comfortable with PHP perhaps I will try this out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd probably display the information in a table, add a delete control column at the end of each row, and some kind of edit in place option. Either turn the row into editable inputs, or slide down an edit row right beneath the row in question when a user wants to edit a record.

Comment: I think this is what I am going to shoot for!

Answer (score 1):

If you have just five fields I would do all remove-update-delete operations on the same page, and creating records in a seperate for like have now.

Basically each  row could have controls edit/delete control at its right, pagination controls  could be a bonus for 50 rows and more. But .. hey, have you not seen any similar layout before?  I seem to be explaining what is the most basic gui layout of most any record based web application.

Comment: I honestly have never seen a table layout ... I have never been into this stuff until recently and I can't stop playing with it! I feel so ... caged in ... I just don't have a mind for this kind of GUI. I like the idea to draw it out below. In your opinion, if I were to have an edit button to the right, when I clicked on the edit button would that bring up a page with five text boxes side by side, and just put the relative information in each text box, so that I would have the ability to edit the row myself?

Answer (score 0):

You could mock the page up using good old fashioned pen and paper, i do this sometimes when theres a lot going on on a page.  I find it helps me quite a bit.